# CSS All but one with Cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In CSS I want to tell the browser to lower the opacity of all of my images with the same div class except for the one I'm hovering over. I know I can do this with this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        transition: opacity .3;
    }

    .parent:hover > .container:not(:hover) {
        opacity: .3;
    }
</style>
```

However I am working with a bootstrap site and have my pictures in `col-md-2s`. So the direct parent of my `.thumbnail` class will only make the other images in that column go opaque on hover. If anyone knows how to keep it so that all other images of that class go opaque when I hover over one, please tell.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
        <div class="img-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;

    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.col-md-6:hover > .img-container:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bZG6T/35/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change `.col-md-6:hover` to the element which contains all rows, `#parent`:

```css
#parent:hover .img-container:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bZG6T/37/)

Or if you prefer to keep the descendant selector in place:

```css
#parent:hover > .col-md-6 > .img-container:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in my code. Here is the fiddle to the specific code I'm applying it to, The images won't work because they're in a root folder, but if you know how to target the right element or even add an element that will allow it to work I'd be very appreciate. Excuse the messy code http://jsfiddle.net/bZG6T/40/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/bZG6T/41/. If you want to stop the opacity drop when the title is hovered you need to add another `div` around the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/bZG6T/42/

Comment: Wow thank you! I've never worked with not in CSS so this was really driving me crazy because everything I tried seemed like it should work.